# How to add an "Access Denied" page to a .Net 5 WebApp with Identity Windows Authentication

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-identity, .net-5, asp.net5

I am struggling to add a custom "Access Denied" page to our .Net 5 WebApp with Identity Windows Authentication.

I have AddIdentityCookies method in the Startup.cs

```
   services.AddAuthentication(o =>
        {
            o.DefaultChallengeScheme = IISDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            o.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = IISDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            o.DefaultSignInScheme = IdentityConstants.ExternalScheme;
        })
        .AddIdentityCookies(o => { });
```

And ConfigureApplicationCookie

```
  services.ConfigureApplicationCookie(options =>
        {
            // Cookie settings
            options.Cookie.HttpOnly = true;
            options.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(120);

            options.AccessDeniedPath = "/Account/AccessDenied";
            options.SlidingExpiration = true;
        });
```

But it does not work. In case of an Access Denied request I get the simple browser 403 Status Page.

Is there any way to set `CookieAuthenticationOptions.AccessDeniedPath` property to redirect the access denied request to my custom page?

Comment: Sure - you just change the `AccessDeniedPath` value to point to whatever the path of your custom page is. Or you put your custom page at the path that's already configured.

Comment: @MartinCostello It does not work.